# How to do Okta multitenancy?

Tags: multi-tenant, okta

I have multitenant setup for our application for example:

1.t1.xyz.com 
2.t2.xyz.com

I want both to talk to okta for different IDP setup for both the tenants. Like t1.xyz.com should talk to shibboleth and t2.xyz.com should use ping identity or may be another tenant will use okta as an IDP.

Other solutions that I have seen are using different accounts for each tenant which is not feasible. Can we do it using okta applications for diff tenant. Or if anybody has different solution please respond.

Answer (score 1):

We have to identify the tenant from the url. Based on that, in the application, you can have a redirect to the corresponding IDP [Shibboleth or PingIdentity etc].

However, this approach works fine if all the IDP's are talking using a common protocol like OAuth2. I have did one implementation with OAuth2. I did write a generic oauth middleware that can take care of handling any OAuth2 providers.

However, if your idea is to use the Okta as an IDP that internally handles the various IDP's, you will have to initiate the login request using the group [tenant code / id] so that it can lookup the identity provider and redirect accordingly

Comment: Can different groups in okta talk to different IDPs in same instance of okta?

Comment: I am not sure about that, can you please consult with okta